Extract a RAR file while automatically truncating long filenames
I have a lot of rar archives, and some of them contain files whose names are too long for the filesystem. When attempting to extract them using unrar x, I will get the error:
Cannot create [extremely long filename].ext
File name too long

Using any archive utility currently available for Linux, is there one which can automatically shorten the extracted filename while preserving the extension? If an archive can be automatically edited pre-extraction to rectify this issue, that will suffice as well.

Can you show a real example of such a file name? 255 bytes as is the general limit for filename size on Linux is already longer than most, so having such file names in an archive would be surprising and there may be some specific reason for those appearing to be so long that could be better addressed than by just truncating those paths.

Have you try to use 7zip and directly extract the files?

@StéphaneChazelas: Good point. I wonder if they're trying to extract onto a VFAT filesystem, or some other FS Linux supports but which isn't designed as a native Unix / Linux filesystem.

With libarchive's bsdtar (which supports at least some versions of rar files as well as dozens of other archive formats), you could do something like:
bsdtar -'s|\([^/]\{100\}\)[^/]*|\1|gp' -xvvf file.rar

Which would truncate file path components to 100 characters¹. You can change it to:
LC_ALL=C bsdtar -'s|\([^/]\{255\}\)[^/]*|\1|gp' -xvvf file.rar

To truncate to 255 bytes, which is the usual limit on the length of a file name on Linux, but beware it might cut a character in the middle if multi-byte encoded (as in UTF-8 as is the default in most modern locales).
bsdtar can extract but not create rar archives, it can however create more Unix like ones and with generally better compression and can convert archive formats. To create a file.tar.xz file out of your file.rar with file path components truncated to 255 bytes, you could do:
LC_ALL=C bsdtar -'s|\([^/]\{255\}\)[^/]*|\1|gp' -cvvf - @file.rar |
  nice pixz > file.tar.xz

Here using pixz instead of xz -T0 as it produces indexed archives which makes it faster to extract individual archive members (provided you use pixz to do so).
Beware those take the characters / bytes off the end, so the extension for those path components that contain dots will be the first to go, and there's no guard against files ending up with the same name after truncation.
If you know the extensions are all 3 bytes long or less, you can preserve them by changing the substitution to:
LC_ALL=C bsdtar -'s|\([^/.]\{251\}\)[^/.]*|\1|gp' -xvvf file.rar

That is truncate all sequences of bytes other than those representing the / and . characters² to 251 bytes instead of the sequence of bytes other than representing / to 255 bytes.
A smarter way, that would handle extensions of any length and always truncate to 255 bytes, but that requires a version of libarchive with that bug fixed (which hasn't been released yet) would be to do something like:
LC_ALL=C bsdtar -'s|[^/]\{1,\}|~:|gp' \
                -'s|\([^/]*\)\(\.[^/]*\)|\2\1|bg' \
                -'s|\([^/]\{256\}\)[^/]*|\1|bg' \
                -'s|\([^/]*\):\([^/]*\)|\2\1|bg' \
                -'s|\([^/]\{255\}\)[^/]|\1|bg' \
                -xvvf file.rar

That is, for each path component:

append a delimiter (here : which is unlikely to be found in a rar archive as those are more for Microsoft systems where : is special).
move the .extension to the beginning
truncate the result to 256 byte (one extra byte to account for the delimiter).
move the extension back to the end and remove the delimiter.
truncate the path components that are still 256 bytes long after : removal because they didn't have an extension or had an extension that was over 254 bytes long.

Note that the extension of a file called 01. Monarchy 2.0.html.gz is taken as being .gz here, not .html.gz, .0.html.gz nor . Monarchy 2.0.html.gz.

¹ Note that UTF-8 encoded characters can be up to 4 bytes long (formerly 6), so you could still end-up with file names that are 400 bytes long if all characters in them were all in the U+10000 .. U+10FFFF range.
² POSIX does guarantee that the encoding of  . and / be single-byte, invariant across locales and that their encoding be not found in the encoding of any other character in any locale, so it should be a safe thing to do.
